# How to set a k/v after a specific key in ES6 map object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var map = new Map();
map.set('0', foo);
map.set('2', 2000);
```

How can I set `('1', 'bar')` after a specific key-0?

want:

```
map.entries = {
0: {"0", foo },
1: {"1", "bar"}
2: {"2", 2000 }
}
```

Comment: `Map` are insertion ordered. Perhaps you should consider an array.

Comment: @DanielA.White what if my key is a string?Use an array to rebuild the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) of [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in an array, splice the wanted part and make a new map.

```js
var map = new Map(),
    temp;

map.set('0', 'foo');
map.set('2', 2000);
temp = [...map];
temp.splice(1, 0, ['1', 'bar']);
map = new Map(temp);
console.log([...map]);
```

Comment: Amazing solution.